# Maven dockerfile plugin not able to tag the image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-maven-plugin

I am trying to integrate maven dockerfile plugin with my project. I have multiple modules under my maven project. I have modified the **pom.xml** for the module I want to build and tag images as below. Running `mvn dockerfile:build` command builds a creates a `docker-info.jar` under the target folder. I am not sure where the images are being built and when I try to run the `mvn dockerfile:tag` command I see the below error.

> Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.4:tag
>   (default-cli) on project drs-web: The parameters 'repository' for goal
>   com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.4:tag are missing or invalid

Pom.xml:

```xml
    <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <buildArgs>
                                    <WAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.war</WAR_FILE>
                                </buildArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tag</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>tag</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <repository>XXX/XXX-api</repository>
                                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.10-jre8-slim
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
MAINTAINER XXX
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/${WAR_FILE} ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/XXX-api.war
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error you should use the same parameters in two sections of your pom.xml. You didn't define the repository's name for the build goal:

```xml
<configuration>
    <repository>XXX/XXX-api</repository>
</configuration>
```

The fact that **docker-info.jar** was created in your Target directory most likely means that the creation of the docker image completed successfully.

The image should be put to your Docker registry with the name "XXX/XXX-api", and you can check it from a console with the command:

```sh
docker image ls
```

P.S. You can avoid generation of **docker-info.jar** by adding the following parameter to the configuration section of dockerfile-maven-plugin:

```xml
<configuration>
    <skipDockerInfo>true</skipDockerInfo>
</configuration>
```